# Problems creating the proper forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I was hoping someone could help me with a rails issue I have come across today. I am trying to teach myself rails, and was using a rails cast that i found online.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcnfFS_DS8

I ran into a problem with creating forms. For instance the two groups that i have tried creating, asking for a title and a description are not appearing.  Could anybody take a quick look at it for me?

Essentially I ran into the problem based off of 14:25 in the video. My code is exactly (at least i believe) written how the author has it, and i am still running into issues.

```
= simple_form_for @pin, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
-if @pin.errors.any?
    #errors
        %h2
            = pluralize(@pin.errors.count, "error")
            prevented this Pin from saving
            %ul
                - @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                %li = msg

        .form-group
            = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

        .form-group
            = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

        = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: What is the error or issue you are seeing exactly?

Comment: If I have the "btn" class indented to the same line as the f.input, i get a working page.....however it fails to show the title and the description forms.  

If I try following what is in the cast, (basically what i have listed) I wind up getting an error message stating: I have a syntax error.

/_form.html.haml:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

_form.html.haml:21: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

What i have listed up above is all the code that I have, it is only 17 lines long.  So not sure exactly what the fix is.

Comment: for one, you are not ending your `do` with an `end`, which it states in your error message.

Comment: @Michael this is not ERB - its HAML. HAML uses python style indentation to delimit blocks not `end`. That said start off learning rails and HAML at the same time sounds pretty painful - although I love HAML it is pretty touchy and not very forgiving. Maybe you should start with https://www.railstutorial.org/

Comment: @papirtiger - that is still an end ;)

Comment: Hi @papirtiger, thank you so much for the help and advice.  The reason why i am choosing HAML instead of erd's is because the company I work for is built off of rails and uses haml.   So i'll try to keep plugging with haml, but we'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

[HAML](http://haml.info/) uses indentation to denote blocks. In your code you had indentented your inputs under `-if @pin.errors.any?` which means the view only renders the inputs if there are any errors:

```
-if @pin.errors.any?
    # ...
    .form-group
        = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

    .form-group
        = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
    = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Pay careful attention to the levels of indentation here:

```
= simple_form_for @pin, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
   -if @pin.errors.any?
   #errors
      %h2
         = pluralize(@pin.errors.count, "error")
         prevented this Pin from saving
      %ul
         - @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
         %li = msg
   # end if
   .form-group
      = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

   .form-group
      = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

   = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

I would not really recommend HAML if you are just starting out with Rails or Ruby. Its really fussy about indentation and can be quite frustrating for a beginner (well unless you're good at Python). There are plenty of more beginner friendly tutorials which do not use HAML.

Comment: I did take a look at the code that you presented with me, and still ran into another issue. I wound up pasting your code in replace of mine, and again received a syntax error. At first it was with the "end if" section, i resolved it by getting rid of the spacing between the % and the words, but afterwords i received another error only this time it  I am getting  "syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end "

:(

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue here! (well with a little help from a friend)

The issue is in the opening statement of the haml file. This line right here, '%li = msg' needs to be indented a one further line forward.

Like this

```
-if @pin.errors.any?
    #errors
        %h2
            = pluralize(@pin.errors.count, "error")
            prevented this Pin from saving
            %ul
                - @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                    %li = msg
```